# python code only reading partial csv file from gcs bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-composer

I am facing a strange issue while reading a csv file from Google cloud storage bucket and writing it to a file in different folder in the same bucket.

I have a csv file named test.csv with 1000001 lines in it. I am trying to replace  " in each line with blank space and write to a file called cleansed_test.csv.

I tested my code in local and works as expected.

below is the code i am using in my local

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re
new_lines=[]
new_lines_error_less_cols=[]
new_lines_error_more_cols=[]
with open('c:\\Users\test_file.csv','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(len(lines))
    for line in lines:
        new_line = re.sub('["]','',line)
        new_line= new_line.strip()
        new_lines.append(new_line)
#         elif line.count('|') < 295:
#             new_line_error_less = re.sub('["]','inches',line)
#             new_line_error_less= new_line_error_less.strip()
#             new_lines_error_less_cols.append(new_line_error_less)
#         else:
#             new_line_error_more = re.sub('["]','inches',line)
#             new_line_error_more= new_line_error_more.strip()
#             new_lines_error_more_cols.append(new_line_error_more)
    new_data = pd.DataFrame(new_lines)
    print(new_data.info())
    #new_data.to_csv('c:\\cleansed_file.csv',header=None,index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

[image]
But when i try doing the same file in gcs bucket only 67514 rows are being read 
code I am using in composer

```
def replace_quotes(project,bucket,**context):
        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        import csv
        import os
        import re
        import gcsfs
        import io
        fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='project_name')
        updated_file_list = fs.ls('bucketname/FULL')
        updated_file_list = [ x for x in updated_file_list if "filename" in x ]
        new_lines=[]
        new_lines_error_less_cols=[]
        new_lines_error_more_cols=[]
        for f in updated_file_list:
            file_name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
            parse_names = file_name.split('/')
            filename = parse_names[2]
            bucketname  = parse_names[0]
            with fs.open("gs://"+f,'r') as pf:
                lines = pf.readlines()
                print("length of lines----->",len(lines))#even here showing 67514
                for line in lines:
                    new_line = re.sub('["]','',line)
                    new_line= new_line.strip()
                    new_lines.append(new_line)
            new_data = pd.DataFrame(new_lines)
            #new_data.to_csv("gs://"+bucketname+"/ERROR_FILES/cleansed_"+filename+".csv",escapechar='',header = None,index=False,encoding='utf-8',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

[image]

Also in the bucket i see the sizes of the files test.csv and cleansed_test.csv are the same.

The only thing i can think of is since files are compressed in gcs buckets should i be opening the files in a different way. cuz when i download the files to local they are lot larger than what i see in the bucket.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: It’s difficult to know what’s going on when you introduce a comparison between local and gcs with very different code.

Comment: Have you tried making your code read from gcs and write to a local file? Have you tried comparing what happens with a much smaller file (e.g. 100 lines?)? Does your ‘csv” files have values which include cr/lf? Does your file have values which include ‘,’ because this would mean the value is surrounded by “ which will completely break your code which processes the csv file as text. You should edit into your question a __minimal__ [mre]

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I wanted to do my deligence again  first before continuing this thread forward. @barny hey although the codes look a little different because one is in my local another is on gcp bucket but the logic is exactly the same.

Comment: Aso this issue is not something I can reproduce as i can successfully run everything in my local. But here is my observations. We recieve a csv file into our bucket from sap dataservices the file is compressed inside the bucket but the extension of the file is .csv and not.gz and compressed size is 59 mb(actual size is 900 mb). and when i try to create another csv from this file logicaly everything is working but when new file reaches the size of 59 mb thats when the data writing to the file is stopped.

Comment: So basically my question is how can i read the entire file.(also the compression used on dataservices side is gzip) but extension of the compressed file in bucket is .csv so i am not sure how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any one curious this is how to inflate a file that has extension .csv  but actually is compressed with gzip.
gsutil cat  gs://BUCKET/File_Name.csv | zcat |  gsutil cp -  gs://BUCKET/Newfile.csv

The only issue here i see is 
i  cant use wild cards or i should say to put it plainly we have to give the destination file name

the down side is since i have to specify the destination file name i cannot use it in bash operator in airflow(this is what i thik i may be wrong)

thanks

any ways hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want by using the replace method of the dataframe column object, and specifying the bool true parameter (otherwise field string must perfectly match the condition of matching character). In this way you can simply iterate per each column and replace the unwanted string, rewriting each column with the newly modified one afterwards.

I modified a bit your code and ran it on my VM in GCP. As you can see I preferred to use the Pandas.read_csv() method as the GCSF one was throwing me some errors. The code seems doing its job as I initially tested by replacing a dummy common string and it worked smoothly.

This is your modified code. Please also note I refactored a bit the reading part as did not properly match the path of the csv in my bucket.

```
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
import re
import gcsfs
import io
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-project')
updated_file_list = fs.ls('test-bucket/')
updated_file_list = [ x for x in updated_file_list if "simple.csv" in x ]
new_lines=[]
new_lines_error_less_cols=[]
new_lines_error_more_cols=[]


for f in updated_file_list:
        file_name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
        print(f, file_name)
        parse_names = file_name.split('/')
        filename = parse_names[1]
        bucketname  = parse_names[0]
        with fs.open("gs://"+f) as pf:
            df = pd.read_csv(pf)
            #print(df.head(len(df)))  #To check results
            for col in df:
                if is_string_dtype(df[col]):
                    df[col] = df[col].replace(to_replace=['"'], value= '', regex= True)
            #print(df.head(len(df))) #To check results

        new_data = pd.DataFrame(df)
        #new_data.to_csv("gs://"+bucketname+"/ERROR_FILES/cleansed_"+filename+".csv",escapechar='',header = None,index=False,encoding='utf-8',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
```

Hope my efforts solved you issue...

Comment: Hi Federico thanks for your inputs but my problem is I should inflate the csv file and then read it but since my compressed file has an extension(.csv) and not .gz I am not sure how to deflate it. Logically my code works its just it reads and writes only until the file size (copressed) is reached and then stops.